# Run/Watch One Specific Task Gulp

Tags: gulp, laravel-5.3, gulp-watch, laravel-elixir

I have recently learnt gulp and found it amazing. Now I am trying to use with `laravel-elixir`

> What I want to achieve is that I should be able to run/watch one specific task.

Below is **gulp.js** file

```
var angularPlugins = ['angular/angular.min.js', 'angular/angular-route.min.js',
'angular/angular-animate.min.js'];

var cssPlugins = ['angular-material.min.css', 'admin.css','helpers.css'];

var appScripts = ['admin_files/js/admin.js','admin_files/js/app-config.js',
   'partials/admin/login/logincontroller.js'
];

elixir(mix => {
      mix.styles(cssPlugins,'','public/admin_files/css');
      mix.scripts(angularPlugins,'public/js/angular.js','public/admin_files/js');
      mix.scripts(appScripts,'public/js/app.js','public/');

});
```

Now I want to watch only `appScripts`. How do I do that?